# How to show that the trace of a regularized Laplacian defined on two sphere with radius $h\geq 1$ is diverging logarithmically?

Tags: eigenvalues, laplacian, traces, regularization

Let $h,m\in[1,\infty)$. I would like to verify that the following sum diverges logarithmically
\begin{equation}
\sum_{d=0}^{\infty} \frac{2d+1}{2h^2(1+\frac{d(d+1)}{h^2})(1+\frac{d(d+1)}{h^2m ^2})^{2}}\,.
\end{equation}
Roughly, it should be proportional to $\log(m^2)$. Since, we know that the Green function of Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^2$ diverging logarithmically. I got this sum as the trace of resolvent of some regularization of Laplacian defined on two sphere of radius $h$. I wonder if I can make use of "Selberg’s Trace Formula"? I would be enormously pleased if someone could explain it to me.  Many thanks.

Comment: Some general techniques: (a) try estimating a single dyadic block $\sum_{2^{j-1} \leq d < 2^j}$ first, then sum in $j$ later.  (b) The point of working with a dyadic block is that one can greatly simplify algebraic expressions up to constants.  For instance, if $2^{j-1} \leq d < 2^j$, then $d$ and $d+1$ are both comparable to $2^j$.  (c) Up to constants, one can approximate the sum of two non-negative quantities $a+b$ by $a$ when $a \gtrsim b$ and $b$ when $b \gtrsim a$.  This will help you simplify expressions such as $1 + d(d+1)/h^2$ after splitting into cases.

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you very much. My idea was to write this sum as an integral using floor function, then split the integration between $0\leq d<1$ and $1\leq d<\infty$. The first interval causes no problem as it is converging but the second one is problematic. I will try your suggestion. Thank you once again.